# How can I concatenate yyyyMMdd at the end of my txt file in ssis?

Tags: csv, ssis, etl, flat-file, derived-column

I am using SSIS to transform my data. My file_name is test_heathcare.csv. How can I bring it to my flat file destination as new derived column being filename as test_healthcare20190712.txt?

If anyone know please help me .

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: @Yahfoufi, Not yet . Still waiting for more response .

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion below? If you are looking to using derived column to change destination, it is impossible. The only way to use dynamic file path as destination is using expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expressions to achieve that:

1. Store your file path within a variable.
2. Then click on the destination *Flat File Connection Manager*. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to show the properties tab.
3. Go to Expressions property
4. From tge expressions window select the `ConnectionString` property and use a similar expression:

   ```
   REPLACE(@[User::FilePath],".csv","20190712.txt")
   ```

**Additional Information**

- [Dynamic Flat File Connections in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1084/dynamic-flat-file-connections-in-sql-server-integration-services/)